# SwipeRefreshLayout with a RecyclerView empty and a TextView

Tags: android, fragment, android-recyclerview, swiperefreshlayout

The problem I have is perfectly explained here http://innodroid.com/blog/post/recycler-empty-swipe-refresh and is realted to dealing with emtpy recyclerview inside a SwipeRefreshLayout. The solution is in that link but I don't have idea how to implement it.

This is my code

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                              android:id="@+id/swipeRefresh"
                                              android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                              android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/background"
            android:id="@+id/rv"
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/empty_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:text="No hay conexión con el servidor" />
    </FrameLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

and this is my Fragment where I cannot extend another class because I already extend Fragment.

```
public class FragmentNoticias extends Fragment {

    private RVAdapter adapter;
    private String mNoticias = "Resumen";
    private SwipeRefreshLayout refreshLayout;
    private Cursor cursor;

    public interface RefreshCall {

        boolean onMethodRefreshCall();
    }

    private RefreshCall mRefreshCall;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        cursor = FeedDatabase.getInstance(getActivity()).obtenerEntradas(mNoticias);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recycler_view, container, false);
        RecyclerView rv = (RecyclerView) root.findViewById(R.id.rv);

        rv.setHasFixedSize(true);

        //hace que el RecyclerView se muestre por defecto con un layout linear
        LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        rv.setLayoutManager(llm);

        adapter = new RVAdapter(
                getActivity(),
                cursor);
        rv.setAdapter(adapter);


        // Obtener el refreshLayout
        refreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) root.findViewById(R.id.swipeRefresh);

        refreshLayout.setColorSchemeResources(
                R.color.s1,
                R.color.s2,
                R.color.s3
        );

        // Iniciar la tarea asíncrona al revelar el indicador
        refreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(
                new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onRefresh() {
                        new HackingBackgroundTask().execute();
                    }
                }
        );

        try {
            this.mRefreshCall = ((RefreshCall) getActivity());
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException("Activity must implement AdapterCallback.");
        }


        return root;
    }

    private class HackingBackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Cursor> {...}
```

How should I implement the solution of the link to use it in my fragment ? I'm confused.

**EDIT**

Thanks to the first answer it works but the refresh circle animation isn't showed correctly yet.

Comment: Try to use SwipeRefreshLayoutWithEmpty instead of SwipeRefreshLayout  in layout file.

Comment: Hacking background task, good name! why not set visible(Gone) to recycler view and setvisible (Visible) text view when the call to HackingBAckgroundTask is empty?

Comment: @mhkore can you  specifically tell what you want to implement in the above question?

Comment: @Amit Specifically it is : I call my database -> if empty-> instead recyclerview I show a TextView "no data connection" -> Once I refresh and my database is full -> show recyclerview with items

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In place of **`android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout`** use **`yourpackagename.SwipeRefreshLayoutWithEmpty`** in your layout. 
(Replace `yourpackagename` with the path to your `SwipeRefreshLayoutWithEmpty` class).

Answer (score 0):

In adition to sJy answer, you should also replace in your Fragment:

`private SwipeRefreshLayout refreshLayout;` with `private SwipeRefreshLayoutWithEmpty refreshLayout;`

and

```
refreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(
                new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onRefresh() {
                        new HackingBackgroundTask().execute();
                    }
                }
        );
```

with

```
refreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(
                new SwipeRefreshLayoutWithEmpty.OnRefreshListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onRefresh() {
                        new HackingBackgroundTask().execute();
                    }
                }
        );
```